# Why I could use push_back in map but not the back_inserter in set?

Tags: c++

The 11th chapter (about associative containers) of C++ Primer 5th says:

> The associative containers do not support the sequential-container position-specific operations, such as push_front or back. Because the elements are stored based on their keys, these operations would be meaningless for the associative containers.

However, after I practice two exercises, I am confused:

1. Given a `map<string, vector<string>>`, one is asked to add a `vector<int>` to a given `key`, my (working) solution is:

   ```
   using Map = map<string, vector<string>>;
   Map my_map;
   for(string ln; cin >> ln)
      for(string cn; cin >> cn)
          my_map[ln].push_back(cn);
   ```
2. However in the second exercise, assuming c is a multiset of strings and v is a vector of strings, is `copy(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(c));` legal or illegal?

When I use it, I got this error:

> error: 'class std::multiset >' has no member named 'push_back'`

What I have known is `back_inserter` doesn't work since there's no `push_back`.

Comment: It is illegal, as you pointed out, the multiset `c` is missing `push_back`.

Comment: You could use `multiset::insert` to add elements to `c`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann thx for your constructive share.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann and thx for fixed my tedious question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my_map[ln].push_back(cn)` does not call `push_back` on the `map` (`my_map`), it calls `push_back` on the `map`s `mapped_type` which is `vector<string>` - you access this with `operator[]` (`my_map[ln]`).

Your statement `my_map[ln].push_back(cn)` is essentially equivalent to:

```
vector<string>& v = my_map[ln];
v.push_back(cn);
```

Comment: thx for your explanation. It just dawned on me^^ I totally understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

You do not use `push_back` on map. You are using it on a vector of strings contained in map.

`back_inserter` uses `push_back` internally and associative containers lack such method, so it will not work with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`std::inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) instead, that will call [`std::multiset::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/insert)

```
std::vector<std::string> v {"aaa", "bbbb", "ccc"};
std::multiset<std::string> m;
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::inserter(m, m.end()));

for (const auto & x : m)
    std::cout << x << "\n";
```

[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/947998b9f924e0b4)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution doesn't `push_back` to an associative container, but to a vector stored in that. That's something different.

As the primer says, a `multiset` doesn't have the sequential `push_back` method, so you can't use `std::copy(...,...,std::back_inserter(..))` with it.